# Kafka Streams DSL: How to close sub-streams created by stream branching/grouping?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing a Kafka Streams app in Scala and I'm worried about potential memory leaks / overall resource usage.

**Is there a way to signal Kafka to "close" a specific sub-stream created by grouping/branching operation and release related resources?**

To demonstrate potential issue, let's consider an e-commerce application that pushes order status change events to a Kafka topic called *"my-super-input-topic"*. Each order is uniquely identified by *OrderId*, which is used as a Kafka message key.

Let's say we need to compute count of status updates per order and push the results to a *"my-super-output-topic"* topic. The following code snippet demonstrates how to do so in Scala:

```scala
// ...
val builder = new StreamsBuilder
val ktable = builder.stream("my-super-input-topic")
    .groupByKey
    .count

ktable.toStream.to("my-super-output-topic")
// ...
```

As I understand, *.groupBy / .groupByKey* divides source stream into N sub-streams (one per order in our case). Code above does not specify any retention windows, therefore even if a given order (sub-stream) receives an event after hours of inactivity - it will still be correctly processed and an update will be pushed to a sink topic, containing correct aggregated count.

Therefore I make a conclusion that Kafka maintains information about each sub-stream in some kind of internal store.

However, orders have finite lifetime, and after some time order becomes completed, which means a sub-stream related to that order will never receive further events. But Kafka still treats it as a valid one and awaits further messages, and more and more "dead" sub-streams will be accumulated as more and more orders get completed. If Kafka dedicates at least some resources to track each sub-stream, "dead" sub-streams can cause extensive memory usage, even though it is completely unnecessary.

Therefore it would be reasonable to dispose/close specific sub-streams as soon as system understands that the relevant orders are completed.

**Note:** this is a fictional use-case to demonstrate the specific issue, not a real task. Please don't suggest implementing it without Kafka Streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that your aggregation will keep a count for each key forever. However, "sub-stream" are on a per-partition basis and hence, each sub-stream should always contain some data.

Closing parts of the topology is not possible.

If you are worried about unbounded grows of the store of the `KTable`, you can either consider to (1) use a windowed store that will evict old data eventually, (2) use an `aggregate()` instead of count: by default `aggregate()` would just count, but if an order is complete, the UDF can return `null` -- this would delete the key-value pair for the order from the store. (3) Or you consider to not use the DSL but the Processor API that provides more control/flexibility to main a state store (you might also consider the usage of "punctuations").

You might also be interested in: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212